# Abstract class vs simple class in Design Pattern - Strategy

Tags: php, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

Is there a difference between these two methods? If it is, which method is better?

First method.
Using abstract class:

```
//Client class:
class Client extends Context
{
    public function insertData()
    {
        $this->chooseStrategy(new DataEntry());
        $this->algorithm();
    }
    public function findData()
    {
        $this->chooseStrategy(new SearchData());
        $this->algorithm();
    }
    public function showAll()
    {
        $this->chooseStrategy(new DisplayData());
        $this->algorithm();
    }
}
//Context class:
abstract class Context
{
    private $strategy;
    public function chooseStrategy(IStrategy $strategy)
    {
        $this->strategy = $strategy;
    }
    public function algorithm()
    {
        $this->strategy->algorithm();
    }
}
```

Second method.
Use simple class

```
//Client class:
class Client
{
    public function insertData()
    {
        $context = new Context(new DataEntry());
        $context->algorithm();
    }
    public function findData()
    {
        $context = new Context(new SearchData());
        $context->algorithm();
    }
    public function showAll()
    {
        $context = new Context(new DisplayData());
        $context->algorithm();
    }
}
//Context class:
class Context
{
    private $strategy;
    public function __construct(IStrategy $strategy)
    {
        $this->strategy = $strategy;
    }
    public function algorithm()
    {
        $this->strategy->algorithm();
    }
}
```

Both methods use same IStrategy interface and same Strategy class.

Comment: Have you searched for it?

Comment: Why not option 3. Inject instances of `Context` objects and have loosely coupled, maintainable and testable code?

Comment: Have a look at this question. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance

Comment: @PeeHaa can you show example?

Comment: @sgtBOSE Yes I was looking for, but I did not know exactly what to ask.

Comment: @Drumbeg Thank you, now I know what to look for